# How to save random value of seed random sort_by {rand} into list in ruby?

Tags: ruby, sorting

I'm new to ruby. I wanted to save array into value that `rand` evaluates(let's say 0.78346....) number with following strings.

```
rows = ["hello", "nihao", "konnichiwa", "hallo"]
myrand = Random.new(100) # seed - 100
rows.sort_by!{myrand.rand } => result could be - ["nihao ", "hello", "konnichiwa", "hallo"]
```

For example: `[[0.12232, "nihao"],[0.53434, "hello"],[0.333, "konnichiwa"],[0.99, "hallo"]]`

How can I get this array from  `rows.sort_by!{myrand.rand }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the random numbers into an array first:

```
rows = ["hello", "nihao", "konnichiwa", "hallo"]
myrand = Random.new(100) # seed - 100
rows.map { |x| [myrand.rand, x] }.sort! 
=> [[0.27836938509379616, "nihao"], [0.4245175907491331, "konnichiwa"], [0.5434049417909654, "hello"], [0.8447761323199037, "hallo"]]
```

The above shown result should always be the same, although this is `Random`, since the seed is known - for `Random.new(100)` these will always be the first four numbers generated.

You can, technically do exactly what you ask by doing:

```
rows = ["hello", "nihao", "konnichiwa", "hallo"]
myrand = Random.new(100) # seed - 100
rows = rows.map { |x| [myrand.rand, x] }
=>  [[0.5434049417909654, "hello"], [0.27836938509379616, "nihao"], [0.4245175907491331, "konnichiwa"], [0.8447761323199037, "hallo"]] 

myrand = Random.new(100) # resetting back to seed - 100

rows.sort_by!{ myrand.rand }
=> [[0.27836938509379616, "nihao"], [0.4245175907491331, "konnichiwa"], [0.5434049417909654, "hello"], [0.8447761323199037, "hallo"]]
```

Comment: great! but can those 0.12232, 0.53434, 0.333, 0.99 random numbers be exact same as rows.sort_by!{myrand.rand} -s result?

Comment: I don't understand your concern... this solution adds a random number to each element in the array, then it sorts by it (if two random numbers are exactly the same - the two elements will be sorted by their string element, but that is a non-interesting edge case...)

Comment: @KevinOelen This answer is much clear,, you are bit confused I think.

Comment: Basically my question is rows.map { |x| [myrand.rand, x] }.sort! could result [[0.12232, "nihao"],[0.53434, "hello"],[0.333, "konnichiwa"],[0.99, "hallo"]]. but line's rows.sort_by!{myrand.rand} order can be same as above? (["nihao","hello","konnichiwa","hallo"])

Comment: @KevinOelen, @NeilSlater, actually, since the seed is known - the numbers should be easily reproduced - they are `[0.5434049417909654, 0.27836938509379616, 0.4245175907491331, 0.8447761323199037]`, or, sorted - `[0.27836938509379616, 0.4245175907491331, 0.5434049417909654, 0.8447761323199037]`

Comment: @Uri Agassi: Yes I agree, although I am not sure `.sort_by` guarantees that it will evaluate the same as `.map { # sort by block }.sort` in general, it does seem to be the case when I test it.

Comment: @Uri Agassi: The documentation here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21 does explicitly state that the value assignments are made via `.map` which does guarantee the sequence. Worth adding . . . without this guarantee the sequence of block evaluation might not be simple or usable.

Comment: thank you very much all. but in the following case [[0.5623507523876472, ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]], [0.07381531933500263, ["h", "a", "l", "l", "o"]], [0.49993338806153054, ["n", "i", "h", "a", "o"]], [0.6499234734532127, ["k", "o", "n", "n", "i", "c", "h", "i", "w", "a"]]] how can I change it to [[0.5623507523876472, "hello"],[0.07381531933500263, "hallo"], etc] ?

Comment: Copy+paste of the code above returned the expected result. I don't understand how you got the characters split, did you change the code?